# Saving and Loading an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my app to work so that when a user presses a "save" button, an NSMutableArray of strings (the array is called "names") inputted from a textfield will be saved. Naturally I also then want to be able to load the NSMutableArray any time I close/reopen the app.

Right now my save button is an IBAction "save". So in my implementation file I have:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{ 
    NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathforDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myArray", docDir]; 
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:names toFile:fileName];
}
```

First of all, does this seem like it should work? Because multiple times my app crashed when I tried to then press the save button. Second am I right to be creating the file path in the IBAction? Or should I be creating it somewhere else (e.g. under viewDidLoad)?

Second, how and where should I be loading my saved NSMutableArray ("names")?

Many thanks!

Comment: 1. Handling data should be in a data model class, it is not part of the UI. 2. What is `names`, it is fully NSCoding compliant? 3. +10 for using `NSKeyedArchiver` and not `NSUserDefaults`!

Comment: @Zaph "names" is the name of the NSMutableArray I have created (elsewhere in my code) that holds various strings inputted by the user. This is a sort of dumb question, but just to clarify: so I shouldn't have that code under the IBAction?

Comment: What is the actual crash message/stack trace?  Code looks ok at first glance, but maybe it's failing to write the file, maybe there's an object in the array that actually isn't a string, etc.  The error should help.  Also agree with @zaph -> serialize somewhere else (but that's not the cause of the error).  (Maybe save isn't even hooked up to this method?)

Comment: @KirkSpaziani it was saying "Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint"

Comment: I would suggest to execute the io code in a different thread. Your IBAction executes in the main thread and you want to keep it for UI operations.

Comment: There should be more to it either above that message, or if you force it to continue on.  Recreate the crash and take a look at all the output.

Comment: The paradim is Model, View, Controller to seperate the functionality. The model part is the data, in this case a `NSMutableArray` of `NSStrings.` Ideally it is in a seperate class and that class provides access to the data as well as handling saving, etc. This there would be a method perhaps named `save` that handles the details of saving, the location, method, etc. One should not have to make a change the a view controller class inorder to change the saving the data. Futher it is best for the model class not to expose how the data is organized , in this case an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @KirkSpaziani I'm not getting anything under output but under "Auto" it is saying paths = (NSArray *) nil. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: To add a filename, use stringByAppendingPathComponent. This will work for example if the last character of the original is a /.

Comment: It is important to provide exact information on what is happening. There is some message, copy it exactly in full and add that to your question. Ii is a breakpoint, exception, crash, etc?

Comment: @Zaph the program crashes and the line in which the array "paths" is created is highlighted in green with the message:  "Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1"  In the bottom right of xcode it says that the array "paths" is nil. That's all that comes up.

Comment: A breakpoint is not a crash, you may have set a debugger breakpoint. The `NSArray` is nil because that line has not executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few concepts here, first as already said by Zaph are you sure that `names` objects conforms to NSCoding protocol?
If yes those line of codes should do the trick:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;
    // Add to the path a new directory just to keep things ordered
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppData"];
    // If the directory doesn't exist it creates one
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) {
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating directory %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"names.arc"] ;
    //Check if the file alredy exist, if does we remove it or the file manager will trigger an error (it doesn't overwrite automatically)
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;
    }
    // Pass the object that you want to archive, if it is a collection the object inside must support NSCoding protocol
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:<#ObjectsConformToNSCoding#>];
    // Saving to the path
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

}
```

[UPDATE]
As pointed out by Zaph all the errors should be handled correctly or bad things could happen.

Comment: Check you code, it is not handling the errors correctly if the directory does not exist and can not be created. It is best to use `- writeToFile:options:error:` because it has an `error` parameter.

Comment: @Zaph you are right, but I've written just for a "sample" intent.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm still getting a breakpoint at the "NSArray *paths" line

Comment: @Julia What  do you mean "breakpoint at the "NSArray *paths" line"? If is is a breakpoint check to see if there is a one set on that line. It is almost impossible to fail in the line `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`.

Comment: Is probably because you are getting an empty array from NSSearchPath, never happend in my life.

Comment: Yeah it seems that the array is empty @Andrea. Why would that be? What can I do?

Comment: The array is nil because execution has stopped at a breakpoint and the line had not executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The message: "Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1" indicated the program has hit a breakpoint. A breakpoint can be set accidentally or on purpose by clicking on  the line number in the Xcode editor. Breakpoints are used to stop the program execution to allow thew developer to examine the state of execution at that point. Then the program can be resumed.

A breakpoint is not a crash.

Also a a blue colored arrow over the line number is a breakpoint indicator. You can remove it by dragging it to the right or disable it by clicking on (it will dim) or just continuing (Menu Debug:Continue).

To see all breakpoints look at the breakpoint navigator: Command-7.

It is worth the time reading the Xcode documentation WRT debugging.